# Moved my c:\Users directory in Windows 8 to nonstandard location, now my tiles are dead

Tags: windows

I moved my `c:\Users` directory in Windows 8 to nonstandard location (to `d:\Users`, so nothing really shocking), now my standard Microsoft-provided tiles are dead.

I changed the registry as Windows expects, so the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-2975078241-893381282-4224377718-1000`
has the correct path in the `ProfileImagePath` key.

Additionally the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` also has the right directory names.

Does anyone have a solution? The desktop applications are working just fine (thank God), but now the tiles of windows 8 are quite useless.

Does anyone of you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pretty much solved it. You have to right-click -> Uninstall your WinRT app (not "Hide"), goto the Store (who does work without re-installing it, funny enough), and Install it again.

Do this with every app and they will work again.